# Pre-multiplying alpha for DXT5

Tags: opengl, textures, alpha, premultiplied-alpha

I load DDS images (DXT5) with transparent alpha into OpenGL. Because the alpha is not pre-multiplied and can not be pre-multiplied based on DXT5 [specs](http://directxtex.codeplex.com/workitem/667) I get thin black halo around the visible part of the texture because I do some blending operations on GPU.My question is: what can be the best workaround for it.My OpenGL renderer updates scene textures on each frame loading those from IO so if I decompress the DDS then pre-muliply , then compress back I get huge overhead.Another option I thought would be to add another render pass and do the pre-multiply in fragment shader and render to texture,then use it for the main pass.This one adds overhead to the whole pipeline because I already have a descent number of passes.What are additional options here?

Comment: "*My OpenGL renderer updates scene textures on each frame loading those from IO*" You're loading and compressing textures every frame? Why?

Comment: Can't explain here as it is commercial stuff but that is special purpose renderer.It is supposed to work that way :)

Comment: That is ,btw,the reason I use DDS here - to speed up upload time.Ah sorry , I am not compressing the textures in real time.I load ready DDSs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue solved.I had a corrupted DDS texture.The manual pre-multiplication I was doing by default in fragment shader works perfectly with valid DXT5.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have your shader do the pre-multiplication of the alpha in situ, then do whatever you were going to do normally?

There's no need to render that to a texture. Just always pre-multiply in your shader, for *all* textures where you need pre-multiplication.

Comment: That doesn't help.That is why I am trying the workarounds...It doesn't help ,btw , because it happens in MSAA pass so unpremuliplied DDS texture data gets interpolated and sets that nasty halo with thin black border.I figured out that GL_NEAREST removes it but it adds edge pixelation instead if the planeto which the texture applied is scaled a little.

Comment: You can't multisample a DDS texture (unless you're doing it *manually*, in which case it stops being multisampling). So it's not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: By default I run several passes.The first is MSAA.I render geometry in that pass with DDS textures.Now when you say I can't do that ,may be that is the problem?I mean the black halo comes from the fact I do MSAA on DDS with alpha channel?

Comment: @MichaelIV: I mean you cannot create a *multisample texture* that uses a compressed internal format. You seem to be dancing around describing your actual rendering algorithm here, and that's not helping anyone get to the root of your problem.

Comment: I use FBO which is not default. It has msaa attachment texture and I render geometry into that FBO. The geometry  gets texture input from DDS and it works fine except DDS with alpha.